# How to remove duplicate packages between brew and apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, homebrew, linux-mint

Being a noob in Linux I started installing packages left and right, with brew and apt-get on Mint.

Now that I am running out os space, I started to browse these packages and noticed many duplicates (gcc, ag,....etc)

How to remove the duplicates in an efficient way without hurting applications that have dependencies on these applications and keep the newest versions?

Comment: If you've installed packages through package management, old versions should be removed automatically.

Comment: Sure, but how to know which are the duplicates between homebrew and apt-get. Each get installed in its own directory.

Answer (score 1):

1) You output all the packages that you install from the brew.

```
brew list >> brewList.txt
```

2) You output all the packages that you installed from apt-get.

```
dpkg-query -l >> dpkgList.txt
```

3) You output all the intersected packages name from dpkgList.txt and brewList.txt

```
grep -Fx -f brew.txt dpkg.txt >> intersectedList.txt
```

4) Now, remove all intersected packages from apt-get or brew. Note: I am removing packages from apt-get here.

```
sudo apt-get remove `cat intersectedList.txt`

/* if the package name has the same prefix, then you can use 

sudo apt-get remove `cat intersectedList.txt`* 

*/
```

So, the whole bash script that also checks every command ran correctly is as below:

```
brew list >> brewList.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    dpkg-query -l >> dpkgList.txt
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          grep -Fx -f brew.txt dpkg.txt >> intersectedList.txt
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
              sudo apt-get remove `cat intersectedList.txt` /* you can place * after ` symbol, if you want to remove node (or nodejs) */
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                   echo OK
               else
                   echo "Task not completed!"
               fi
            else
              echo "grep -Fx -f brew.txt dpkg.txt error!"
            fi
       else
         echo "dpkg-query error!"
       fi
else
    echo "brew list!"
fi
```

Comment: Nice but there is two problems: 1) packages do not have necessarily the same name in Mint and in homebrew e.g.: `node` in homebrew matches `nodejs` in Mint. 2) Some software are installed and removed through `brew cask` e.g: `jdk`, `wireshark`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this, but you can list installed packages through homebrew with:

```
brew list
```

and then list installed packages through Mint with:

```
dpkg-query -l
```

some packages will have small differences in their names but you will recognize them. You can then remove packages from homebrew with:

```
brew remove <package>
```

and remove packages from Mint with:

```
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

beware that packages installed from homebrew are generally newer than packages installed from Mint.